# NoClassDefFoundError for my own class when creating CallSite with LambdaMetafactory

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, lambda-metafactory

I’m trying to create a small utility to replace my use of reflection across my entire project (mostly for performance benefits of using LambdaMetafactory) but I’m stumbling at the creation of a CallSite. However, the issue only appears to happen when accessing classes that are not my own. Accessing 3rd party libraries or even Java’s own classes (java.lang.Object for instance) will result in a NoClassDefFoundError not for the 3rd party class, but for my interface.

```
public final class Accessor {

    private static Constructor<MethodHandles.Lookup> lookupConstructor;

    static {
        newLookupConstructor();
    }

    protected static void newLookupConstructor() {
        try {
            lookupConstructor = MethodHandles.Lookup.class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.class);
            lookupConstructor.setAccessible(true);
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("MethodHandles.Lookup class constructor (Class) not found! Check java version.");
        }
    }

    private Accessor() { }

    public static <T> T to(Class<T> interfaze, Class<?> clazz, String method, Class<?>... params) {
        try {
            return to(interfaze, clazz.getDeclaredMethod(method, params));
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static <T> T to(Class<T> interfaze, Method method) {
        try {
            MethodHandles.Lookup caller = lookupConstructor.newInstance(method.getDeclaringClass());
            MethodHandle implMethod = caller.unreflect(method);
            CallSite site = LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(caller, method.getName(), MethodType.methodType(interfaze), implMethod.type(), implMethod, implMethod.type());
            // ^ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for the passed interfaze class
            return (T) site.getTarget().invoke();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Unit tests I’ve run demonstrating the issue can be found here:

```
final class AccessorTest {

    @Test // SUCCESS
    @DisplayName("Verify MethodHandles.Lookup constructor")
    void lookupConstructorAvailabilityTest() {
        Assertions.assertDoesNotThrow(() -> Accessor.newLookupConstructor());
    }

    @Test // SUCCESS
    @DisplayName("Verify available matching instance method is called")
    void findMatchingMethodAndCallTest() {
        ObjectAccessor accessor = Accessor.to(ObjectAccessor.class, TestObject.class, "instanceMethod");
        Assertions.assertNotNull(accessor);
        Assertions.assertTrue(accessor.instanceMethod(new TestObject()));
    }

    @Test // SUCCESS
    @DisplayName("Verify available matching static method is called")
    void findMatchingStaticMethodAndCallTest() {
        ObjectAccessor accessor = Accessor.to(ObjectAccessor.class, TestObject.class, "staticMethod");
        Assertions.assertNotNull(accessor);
        Assertions.assertTrue(accessor.staticMethod());
    }

    @Test // FAILURE
    @DisplayName("Verify java.lang.Object#toString works")
    void testDynamicToStringInvokation() {
        ToString accessor = Accessor.to(ToString.class, Object.class, "toString");
        // ^ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmail/justisroot/autoecon/data/AccessorTest$ToString
        Assertions.assertNotNull(accessor);
        Assertions.assertEquals(accessor.toString(Integer.valueOf(42)), "42");
    }

    public interface ObjectAccessor {
        public boolean instanceMethod(TestObject o);
        public boolean staticMethod();
    }

    public interface ToString {
        public String toString(Object o);
    }
}
```

This will throw the following:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/gmail/justisroot/autoecon/data/AccessorTest$ToString
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Unsafe.java:1223)
>       at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:320)
>       at java.base/java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:188)
>       at java.base/java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:317)
>       at com.gmail.justisroot.autoecon.data.Accessor.to(Accessor.java:43)

I’ve been spending way too many hours wracking my brain for solutions. A second pair of eyes would certainly be helpful.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the reason you are hacking into the `Lookup` constructor? If you want to access private methods, why not use `method.setAccessible(true)` + `unreflect(method)`?

Comment: I was getting an IllegalAccessException even for public methods in public classes, when trying to access Java classes or other third party classes. Granting the lookup the permission of FULL_POWER_MODES resolved this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using a `Lookup` object representing the declaring class of the `Method` object. Therefore, when the target method is `Object.class.getDeclaredMethod("toString")`, you are creating a lookup object for `java.lang.Object`, which is loaded by the bootstrap loader.

As a consequence, you can only access classes known to the bootstrap loader, which precludes your own `ToString` interface.

Generally, when combining arbitrary interfaces and target methods, you must find a class loader which knows both. This wouldn’t be required by the underlying generator facility in OpenJDK, but the `LambdaMetafactory` enforces this.

Likewise, it enforces that the lookup object must have `private` access to the lookup class, even when the class is otherwise irrelevant, e.g. when accessing only `public` artifacts. That’s why `MethodHandles.publicLookup()` does not work.

But when both, the `interface` and the target method, are accessible from the class loader of your current code, `MethodHandles.lookup()` should work, without the need to hack into the internals.

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, in order to avoid a NCDFE, I will need to somehow make my interface accessible to the target method’s classloader?
Do you have any ideas for how I might go about achieving that?

Comment: You already have a class loader which can access both. In your example, `Object.toString()` is accessible from `ToString`'s class loader (as the bootstrap loader is the (grand)parent of it). So when you create a lookup object for `ToString`, it will work. Since this is also the class loader of your test code, just using `MethodHandles.lookup()` in this setup would also work here. It's not unusual that the interface and the target method's declaring class have the same loader or loaders with a parent relationship. Really tricky would be two loaders without such a relationship.